# How to remove all columns from JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to remove all columns? Thanks.

Comment: Please describe your `TableModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Faster Way::Dynamic Remove all the Column on JTable

```
//JTable variable name is jTable1_info....
model_info=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1_info.getModel();
//Clear all the column name on jtable jpanel-4
model_info.setColumnCount(0);
```

Before code on this Example

```
//import the DefaultTableModel
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public final class homepage extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    DefaultTableModel model_info;
    public homepage() throws InterruptedException
    {
        initComponents();
        create_column();//call method create jtable column names                
    }
}
private void create_column()
{
    model_info=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1_info.getModel();
    model_info.addColumn("Column_Name");
    model_info.addColumn("Column_type");
    model_info.addColumn("Column_size");        
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using DefaultTableModel, set [column count](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setColumnCount%28int%29) to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
        TableColumnModel cm = jTableThatUCreated.getColumnModel();
        while (cm.getColumnCount()!=0) {                
            TableColumn column = cm.getColumn(0);
            cm.removeColumn(column);
        }
```

Java 7 doesnt setColumnNumber(0) as previous answers.

Comment: Please share descriptin with code snippet. it'll more help to user.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
dtf = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
for (int i = table.getRowCount()-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    dtf.removeRow(i);
}
table.setModel(dtf);
```